# Unable to upload multiple image from multiple button using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my app have two button to choose two image.Then that two image will be uploaded by another upload button.I am using retrofit to upload images.But I am unable to that when I am trying to upload, the last image uploaded two times.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_ID) {

            // Get the User Selected Image as Bitmap from the static method of ImagePicker class
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this.getActivity(), resultCode, data);


            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            panImg = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
        }
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){

            // Get the User Selected Image as Bitmap from the static method of ImagePicker class
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this.getActivity(), resultCode, data);


            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getContext(), bitmap);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            idImg = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
        }
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMG){
            // Get the User Selected Image as Bitmap from the static method of ImagePicker class
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this.getActivity(), resultCode, data);



            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getContext(), bitmap);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            bankImg = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
        }
    }
}
```

this is the api call.

```
MultipartBody.Part filePart = null;
    MultipartBody.Part filePart1=null;
    if (panImg != null){
        filePart1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pan_img",panImg.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),panImg));
    }
    if (idImg != null){
        filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("id_img",idImg.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),idImg));
    }

    Call<KycData> call2 = APIClient.getInstance()
            .updatekyc(
                    filePart1,
                    filePart
            );
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning value to **tempUri** in `onActivityResult` for `PICK_IMAGE_ID` request code.Therefore it is using the value assigned from your other if condition of `onActivityResult`.